# Laravel Eloquent can increment ($collection->increment('field')) fail?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a redirect function that looks like this. For some reason, it looks like it's sometimes missing to increment the item. I'm wondering if it sometimes can be so that it misses this because some caching or something?

```
public function redirect($key)
{
    $item = $this->items->findOrFail($key);

    $item->increment('redirects');

    $encode = urlencode($item->_url);

    return view('item.redirect', ['url' => ($encode)]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about topic of your question. Do you get such method somewhere from Laravel?

I don't know what is `$key` here but you should make sure this is single id (for example 2) and not array.

For single model:

```
$item->increment('redirects');
```

will work

but if `$key` sometimes is array then

```
$item = $this->item->findOrFail($key);
```

will be collection, so `increment` method would cause error, because there is no `increment` method on Eloquent collection.

Comment: $key is a unique identifier for an item. Comes from the URL and I don't want to use the ID. It will never be an array. The problem I have is that the increment is not always triggered and I can't figure out how to track this.

Comment: Have you verified error log? What's in there? What is `$this->item` Are you sure that for model you use `increment` there is `redirects` column in table?

Comment: There is nothing in the log. $this->item is actually $this->items. I edited it wrong. I fetch items in the constructor.

Comment: So I think it's impossible to help you without more details. If it's not increased there should be some errors in log. Also you haven't included full code so it's hard to say how exactly you are using it and what are other steps.